# Trying to send multiple Key value inside with function for a Route: Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am using the below function to send the key value to show a message based on database operation.

```
return redirect()->route("Roles")->with("UpdateRole", "updated");
```

Now, I am looking to send a status code key also but as per the doc for with function, we can send one key and it's corresponding value.

Is there any way to send multiple Keys and their corresponding values?

Comment: why don't you use an array?

Comment: using with function I can have one key only.

Comment: keys inside an array?

Comment: Exactly. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.html#method_with):

```
RedirectResponse with( string|array $key, mixed $value = null)
```

This should works:

```
return redirect()->route("Roles")->with([
  "key1" => "value1", 
  "key2" => "value2" 
]);
```

Comment: yes that should work just fine, or calling `with` multiple times

Answer (score 0):

What you want is referred to as flashing data. [Redirecting With Flashed Session Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) introduces the topic.

What is not explicit but is possible is to use more than one `->with()`.

```php
return redirect()->route("Roles")
    ->with("page_view_time", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
    ->with("user_name", $user->name);
```

Also, as @AlexandreThebaldi [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043826/5816643), the [Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.html#method_with) shows that an array can be used (be sure to use an associative array).

```php
return redirect()->route("Roles")
    ->with('alerts', [
        'success' => 'Congratulations! Account created.',
        'info' => 'Check your email to verify your account.'
    ])
    ->with([
        'user_name' => $user->name,
        'user_score' => $user->score,
        'highest_score' => $highest_score
    ]);
```

It is important to remember that you must know what you will get in your blade template, e.g. array or string / number.